# Flushing PyGaze keypress

Tags: python, keypress

`self.keyboard.get_key()` (from [the PyGaze library](http://www.pygaze.org/)) holds a screen until a key is pressed.

How can I flush/clear the contents of the a key press prior to this call?

At the moment a previous key press is carried into the function where I call `self.keyboard.get_key()`.

Comment: Found what I was looking for. If you call get_key like this`self.keyboard.get_key(flush=True)` it flushes any keypresses made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to flush any keypresses in PyGaze the following should be added to the `get_key` function `self.keyboard.get_key(flush=True)`.